# Triggering Azure WebJobs API over Basic Auth from external PHP app?

Tags: php, api, azure

As per the title - I'm trying to trigger an Azure Website "triggered" WebJob from our custom PHP deployment application hosted external to Azure websites.

Thanks to what I believe is Active Directory, I'm able to navigate the /api URLs in my browser and get a JSON output without having to reauthenticate. For example, /api/triggeredwebjobs outputs the triggered WebJob information (that I've set up inside Azure Portal) in my browser.

I've gotten as far in my PHP app as sending a POST request and it is successfully authenticating using basic auth, but every single /api URL that I set in my PHP app returns:

```
"No route registered for '/api/triggeredwebjobs/{webjobname}'"
```

where {webjobname} is my custom name for the web job, hidden for privacy of the client. Every URL returns this, but if I navigate in my browser, I only get that error if I navigate to a URL that doesn't exist, such as /api/blahblahblah.

I've set up a deployment user which is what it's using to authenticate... I've even logged in to https://{azuresite}.scm.azurewebsites.net/basicauth using the deployment user and successfully gotten output from each /api page in my browser.

If it helps, I'm using Httpful.phar to handle the HTTP requests.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read and possibly assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague helped me get to the bottom of this - the documentation was out of date. I have opened an issue on the Kudu Github Repo to get them to review this:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1466

To solve the issue for future readers of this question, the correct URL to use within the requester app is:

https://{yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net/jobs/triggered/{jobname}/run

Good luck!